# Limits in Banach space are convergent

Tags: limits, convergence-divergence, banach-spaces

I'm stuck on this problem:

Let $X$ be a normed space, and let $(T_n)_{n\in \mathbb N}$ be a convergent sequence with limit $T$ in Banach space $L(X)$.

If $S \in L(X)$,then how to show that $(ST_n)_{n \in \mathbb N}$ is convergent in $L(X)$, with limit $ST$?

Comment: Take the proof of this fact for numbers $T_n,T, S$ and imitate it for operators $T_n, T, S$.  In particular, replace the triangle inequality for numbers with the triangle inequality for the operator norm.

Comment: I know that ‖+‖⩽‖‖+‖‖, but how would it help to prove the convergence?

Comment: An unrelated note: $L(X)$ is a Banach space if and only if $X$ is Banach, yet you say that $X$ is only a normed space.

Answer (score -1):

We have
$$\|ST - ST_n\|_{L(X)} = \|S(T - T_n)\|_{L(X)} \le \|S\|_{L(X)}\|T- T_n\|_{L(X)}.$$
We conclude as $T_n \to T$ in $L(X)$.

Comment: Why the down vote?